# Transfer CSV File from GCS to BQ using DataFlow Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a list of CSV Files in GCS Bucket. I want to Load those files in BQ.

**BEFORE LOADING ALL COLUMNS NEEDED CONVERT INTO STRING TYPE**

I am using Dataflow Template **Text File on Cloud Storage To BigQuery**
Where a **JavaScript UserDefinedFunction(UDF)** needed to be mentioned and a **JSON** For Defining the **BigQuerytable Schema**.

In JSON Schema needs to Convert each **Column as a String**. (It's a **Tedious Task** as each CSV has 50+ column and I have to manually write column name  in UDF and JSON )

Is there any Approach to DO this?

Comment: Javascript UDF is javascript. Make a loop and perform your conversion like that. Did you have a try?

Comment: but each CSV has different Column header

Comment: So, it's different table, and thus different dataflow. You can create a template that you customize (with custom code) when you submit  a job.

Comment: as Guillaume said, you can create your own customize data flow template. You will have to have a data flow job for every table. I had a similar requirement where I created my won data flow template for every table to read from cloud storage bucket and load into big query. I could do some small transformations while loading in bigquery.